# 'Bad Data' When decrypting messages using DES3

Tags: c#, encryption

C# 2008

I am using the following code to encrypt and encrypt a message. However, when I attempt to decrypt I get a 'Bad Data' error.

Is there anything wrong with my code below?

Many thanks,

```
public string encryptText(string text)
    {
        try
        {
            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider encrypt = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            encrypt.Key = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 144, 89, 55, 34, 21, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
            encrypt.IV = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34 };
            byte[] byteText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = encrypt.CreateEncryptor();

            byte[] encryptedText = encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(byteText, 0, byteText.Length);

            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(encryptedText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);

            return ex.Message;
        }

    }

    /// Decrypt the text
    public string decryptText(string encryptedText)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytesText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(encryptedText);

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider decrypt = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

            decrypt.Key = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 144, 89, 55, 34, 21, 13, 8, 5, 3, 2, 1, 0 };
            decrypt.IV = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34 };

            ICryptoTransform decryptor = decrypt.CreateDecryptor();

            byte[] originalText = decryptor.TransformFinalBlock(bytesText, 0, encryptedText.Length);

            return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(originalText);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex.Message);

            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

You're taking the encrypted bytes and converting them to a string using `Encoding.Unicode`, but then you're taking the string and converting it back to bytes using `Encoding.Default`. That's pretty much *guaranteed* not to work (unless the default happens to be UTF-16).

However, you should use *either* of these - converting arbitrary binary data to text using an encoding is a bad idea. Use `Convert.ToBase64String` (in the encryptor) and `Convert.FromBase64String` (in the decryptor) instead.

(I'd also very much query the wisdom of returning an exception message as if it were the successful result of encrypting/decrypting, but hopefully you only did that for the sake of the sample code.)

Comment: So, assuming the `stringToDecrypt` is created using `Convert.ToBase64String`,is this an acceptable method of decryption? `inputByteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(_decodedString);  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();  CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateDecryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);  cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length);  cs.FlushFinalBlock();  System.Text.Encoding encoding = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();  return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());` [many apologies for the formatting..i cannot seem to set a line break]

Comment: @TimDog: Yes, although I'd use `Encoding.UTF8` instead of calling the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, there are a few mistakes  in the code.

- encryptedText and bytesText must be the same byte array. As Jon Skeet suggest you could use Base64 encoding.
- The IV is part of the ciphertext. Hence you don't have to set the IV when you decrypt.
- The default mode of encryption is CBC. This mode requires that IV is random (rsp. unpredictable). Hence you must not set a fixed IV, when you encrypt. When you create the CryptoServiceProvider a random IV is already set. Hence overwritting the IV with a fixed value decreases your security.
- Putting a key explicitly in the code isn't a great idea. I hope you'll change this once your code leaves the experimental state.
- Is there a reason to use TripleDes? Otherwise you might want to consider using AES instead.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comments. Just a simple question. How can I use the Base64 as I need to convert my data into a byte array and for that I need to encode? Thanks

Comment: Hello, For putting the key in the code. I would have thought to be safe as once this is complied (using Class library) I will just get a DLL that would be difficult to reverse engineer. However, if this is unsafe practice. Where is the best place to store the key?

Comment: Ok, I can't say for sure how easy it is to find the key using just common tools for inspecting DLLs, but I would certainly not rely on DLLs keeping any information secret. More common is to keep the keys in separate key files. This simplifies the key management, since it is more clear where the sensitive information is.